# WebDriver getText() Method with Replace <br> Tag

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Html Code

```
<td class="left-align no-wrap-clmn">
<span style="color:orange">
In
<br>
Process
</span>
</td>
```

Webdriver to get the In Process value using getText method

Code:

```
String status = driver.findElement(By
                        .xpath("//*[@id='tblPortfolio']/tbody/tr[" + row
                                + "]/td[13]")).getText();
```

for the Above code Return the value with Following format

Output for the above

```
In
Process
```

after that i will pass the above value with IF Statement
Code:

```
if (status.equals("In Process") {

}
```

issue:

its not get into the IF Statment, because of the new Line char
so how can i make an output with "`In Process`" (with my getText()) or any changes in IF Statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the new line character, try this :

```
status.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");
```

It will remove all line breaks with space.

Comment: @Prabu: If this answer is what you were looking for, please mark it, so that others who search for the answer to this question will be guided straight to this one.. Thanks. :)