# java - Extract text which contains <br> tag with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to extract text from following HTML code :

```
<div>
   "blabla"
   <br>
   "blublu"
   <br>
   "blibli"
</div>
```

I'm using getAttribute method because the text can be hidden (so getText() can possibly return null) :

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.tagName("div")).getAttribute("textContent");
System.out.println(text);
```

the expected result is

```
blabla\nblublu\nblibli
```

however I get

```
blablablublublibli
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebDriver getText() Method with Replace <br> Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341052/webdriver-gettext-method-with-replace-br-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved by using

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.tagName("div")).getAttribute("innerText");
```

and not

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.tagName("div")).getAttribute("textContent");
```

Comment: Not working for me... `.getAttribute("innerText")` returns the text without line breaks as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getText()` method on the `WebElement`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div")).getText()
```

Output would be something like:-

```
"blabla"
"blublu"
"blibli"
```

Comment: getText() isn't a good solution because I need to get this text even when div is hidden. This method return null in this case